# No notifications of the Like button on my facebook?

Tags: facebook, button, notifications, facebook-like

When I click on the "like button" in my [website](http://www.johanna-vaude.com), there are no notifications on my facebook page. For old articles on my website I can see notifications on facebook when I "like" but it doesn't work for the new articles.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to your activity log in facebook in order to make sure that the like button does work. if you didn't see anything from the activity log, this probably means the like button is not working.

Comment: I looked in my activity log and when I like this page: [Example] (http://www.johanna-vaude.com/color-shoot-sur-blow-up-special-ete-indien-sur-arte/), I've a notification and when I like this page: [Example 2] (http://www.johanna-vaude.com/france-culture-la-vignette-par-aude-lavigne-johanna-vaude-invitee/) notification does not appear :-S.